# PayPal IPN sandbox returns HTTP 302

Tags: php, http, paypal

Can someone please explain to me why this keeps returning an HTTP 302 response code?

I've run dozens of test payments through and I'm starting to pull my hair out at this point!

**EDIT**... that second line should be:

`$data = 'cmd=_notify-validate&' . http_build_query($_POST);`

```
$conn = fsockopen("ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com", 443, $n, $m, 30);
$data = http_build_query($_POST);

$headers = 
"POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n" .
"Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n" .
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" .
"Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n";

fputs($conn, "$headers\r\n$data");

// loop until end of response
while (!feof($conn)) {

    $r = fgets($conn, 1024);
    $results .= $r;

    if (strcmp($r, "VERIFIED") === 0) {
        $success = true;
        fclose($conn);
        break;
    }

    if (strcmp($r, "INVALID") === 0) {
        $success = false;
        fclose($conn);
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($results);
```

Gives me:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sun, 05 Apr 2015 01:05:19 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: c9MWDuvPtT9GIMyPc3jwol1VSlO=jpXL4slHSFMW62IfhXt98Ecs62rNGxGaMe9do0PXFTJCvKNoSWrzcNKb58XDiADlB6Vd4sSqrQt-mdqdmwlhYjnS-vrmseHmpUXfgJB02GXawXmw-0ORrjpAlcs9MjNzjerB9260RGRm1oASkzbL6fKubJohZlpTuM9ejW-hubbqKhagUSvvO7jyvT-6qewxY72pyDVtulr0FV3X3b5N8HwihlK2nzr9LK6NbwwmrzH3gOsHz7GQ4Mt7M8y; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: -1ILhdyICORs4hS4xTUr41S8iP0=uyJXnbFu20vqgtvwa1990vbI5M5aG7JM-hGvulSB7_Mg0vU_l6yRwHrZj3FFHc1v8V_6jaqEahhmS6Wt; expires=Sat, 31-Mar-2035 01:05:19 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Wed, 02-Apr-2025 01:05:19 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: consumer_display=USER_HOMEPAGE%3d0%26USER_TARGETPAGE%3d0%26USER_FILTER_CHOICE%3d0%26BALANCE_MODULE_STATE%3d1%26GIFT_BALANCE_MODULE_STATE%3d1%26LAST_SELECTED_ALIAS_ID%3d0%26SELLING_GROUP%3d1%26PAYMENT_AND_RISK_GROUP%3d1%26SHIPPING_GROUP%3d1%26HOME_VERSION%3d1%26MCE2_ELIGIBILITY%3d4294967295; expires=Wed, 02-Apr-2025 01:05:19 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.108.11.1428195919710342; path=/; expires=Tue, 28-Mar-45 01:05:19 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dappdispatcher%26TIME%3D1334452309; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.128.11.1428195919696329; path=/; expires=Tue, 28-Mar-45 01:05:19 GMT
Location: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/home
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=14400
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Notice I *am* using `ssl://` and port 443.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** forgot to include `cmd=_notify-validate` in the POST request data.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com` as your endpoint. I've never had a problem using that as my endpoint

Comment: Interesting, I everything I found said to point it to `ssl://`.  Using `https://` also triggered a server error, likely due to misconfiguration.

Comment: @RecoveringNerdaholic Very strange indeed. I would suggest you switch to CURL instead. [CURL Example](https://gist.github.com/CodeAngry/5957044)